# How to read GCP pubsub message in Java without @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, spring-jms, spring-cloud-gcp

My requirement is to read gcp pubsub message in java. I have implemented it using java scheduler and google-cloud-pubsub maven dependency(https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull). Its a Pull subscriptions not Push.
But same implementation was not accepted by reviewer. It was rejected by saying implement the same without Java scheduler and asked me to refer this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/

I tried POC with above link and its working fine with spring-boot but issue is its not supported using spring with version: 5.1.3.RELEASE that we are using.

Can someone please help me or provide any reference that I can try to implement GCP pubsub read msg without Java scheduler and it supports spring version: 5.1.3.RELEASE.

Comment: You should ask your reviewer what scheduling library they want you to use instead

Comment: @Jorn they are looking for solution provided by gcp sdk itself like its implemented on second link that I have provided or somehow using JMS that I am not sure.